What is this plant disease that causes raised blobs in the leaves?
I found this plant in Borneo with seemingly diseased leaves. The leaves have raised reddish blobs. What could be the cause of such deformities?



I don't know a specific answer, but in addition to pathogens like bacteria, viruses, and nematodes, also consider gall-forming insect.

@Flux Could you please confirm a specific location? There are multiple places in the world that could be referred to as: Borneo. This is in the Gall and Rust mite Family, but in order to confirm a species I need a specific location.

Not a disease per se (at least not caused by any fungus, bacteria, or virus, which would not lead to raised bumps). Most likely these are galls caused by parasitic eriophyid mites.
Without a more specific location or more specific info about plant species/etc. on your post, I will not try to identify specifically.

note: not that it much matters, as the specific species is not likely described. From Wikipedia:


About 3,600 species have been described, but this is probably less than 10% of the actual number existing in this poorly researched family.

Instead, I'll show you similar looking growths caused by maple gall mites:

 Image source: University of Wisconsin-Madison Extension 
